# Airflow server execution date

Tags: airflow

[image: the execution date does not show year starting from January 2021]

Monthly days are not getting scheduled and I think the absence of year in the execution date could be the reason.

Comment: The year is absence because Airflow doesn't show the current year. This is how it was designed. As for your image it shows all dates for daily execution. It's not clear what is missing and what is "monthly days"

Answer (score 2):

The year is absence because Airflow doesn't show the current year. This is how it was designed. As for your image it shows all dates for daily execution.